# How to index a newly created column name inside a loop

Tags: r, loops

I am using the data set `mtcars` as my example. The goal is to:

- Step 1: Use a loop to run regressions with changing outcome, while the independent variables stay the same for each model.
- Step 2: Transform the residuals from each model in step 1

My code:

```
library(tidyverse)

data("mtcars")

# Plan:
# Step 1: Outcome = cyl + disp + hp + drat
# Step 2: Transform residual from step 1

# The outcomes are all the other columns 
outcome = colnames(mtcars[, -c(2:5)])

for (i in outcome) {
  # Step 1: Run the model using a loop with changing outcome
  formula = as.formula(paste0(i, "~ cyl + disp + hp + drat"))
  model = lm(formula, data = mtcars, na.action = na.exclude)
  
  # Save the residuals from each model as new columns with the suffix '.res'
  mtcars[, paste0(i, ".res")] = residuals(model)
  
  # Step 2: Transform the residuals and save them as new columns with the suffix '.invn'
  mtcars[, paste0(i, ".invn")] =
    qnorm((rank(mtcars[,get(paste0(i,".res"))],na.last="keep")-0.5)/sum(!is.na(mtcars[,get(paste0(i,".res"))])))
}
```

However, I am getting an error `Error in get(paste0(i, ".res")) : object 'mpg.res' not found` and this is from step 2.

- The reason I think is because when indexing a column from a data set using `[]`, the column name has to be put in quotes. So, if I were to put `mtcars[, 'mpg.res']` I would have not received this error.
- Nonetheless, the problem is that the column names are changing depending on the `i` so I can't put `paste0(i, ".res")` in quotes.
- In summary, my question is: How to index a newly created column when the column name is part of the loop? I tried `eval(parse())` but it didn't work.

PS: I know I can use `purrr::map` or `apply` to make my life easier, but I would really like to learn how to solve this problem when using a loop.

Comment: It would be better to create needed columns beforehand and then just insert the values. Even better would be to use list. Before loop results <- list(), inside the loop resutsl[[paste(i, ".res")]] <- res(model).

Comment: @jyr Did you mean having `results <- list()` and then replacing `mtcars[,paste0(i,".res")]` with `results[[paste(i, ".res")]]` throughout the code? The results will then be in a big list and will need one more step to convert the list to a dataframe. Could you elaborate why is this a better way?

Comment: See Growing Objects from R inferno on explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `get()`

```r
# Step 2: Transform the residuals and save them as new columns with the suffix '.invn'
  mtcars[, paste0(i, ".invn")] =
    qnorm((rank(mtcars[,paste0(i,".res")],na.last="keep")-0.5)/sum(!is.na(mtcars[,paste0(i,".res")])))
```

Comment: I can't believe is this simple. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach might be to always use the last column name, since you always append the column to the end of the `data.frame`.

```
mtcars[, colnames(mtcars)[length(colnames(mtcars))]]
```

Translating your code into:

```
mtcars[, paste0(i, ".invn")] =
    qnorm((rank(mtcars[, colnames(mtcars)[length(colnames(mtcars))]],na.last="keep")-0.5)/sum(!is.na(mtcars[, colnames(mtcars)[length(colnames(mtcars))]])))
```